# Combine two commands in linux and append it to another file

Tags: linux, command

awk -F "," '{print $1, $5}' < Task.txt > Task_mod.txt   //this works fine

sed '/^\s*$/d'   //this removes the blank lines

I am trying to put these commands together in linux and append it to Task_mod. Any ideas on how to put it together? It doesn't work with the pipe command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with the pipe.

```
awk -F "," '{print $1, $5}' < Task.txt | sed '/^\s*$/d'  > Task_mod.txt
```

EDIT:

- If you want to append you need to use >> instead of >
- What errors do you see when you run it with the pipe? I did it and I think it works...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in single command itself :

```
awk -F "," 'NF>1 {print $1, $5}' Task.txt > Task_mod.txt
```